# Visit same case twice in Kotlin 'when' block?

Tags: kotlin

I have 3 radio buttons, A, B, C. For *A* I want to call `foo()`. For *B* I would like to call `bar()`. And for *C*, I would like to call `bar()` **and** `baz()`.

Below is the code I currently have that does not work (although hopefully my intentions are clear)

```
when (item.id) {
    R.id.button_a -> foo()
    R.id.button_b, R.id_button_c -> bar()
    R.id.button_c -> baz() // Duplicate label in when
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to use multiple `when` blocks or `if/else` blocks instead?

Comment: Relevant: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540/5

Answer (score 3):

You can do somthing like:

```
when (item.id) {
            R.id.button_a -> foo()
            R.id.button_b -> bar()
            R.id.button_c ->{
                bar()
                baz()
            }
        }
```

Comment: This approach would the most obvious and best one for my little example above, except in our real code, bar() is really long, and it has reference to item.id so I'd to avoid writing bar() twice if possible, as it would end up really verbose.

Comment: Just write an actual `bar` function so you can call it twice succinctly.

Comment: Only one button at a time can trigger so calling same `bar()` twice should not be a problem i guess

Comment: If you're concerned about a `bar` function being too far from your current code, or without access to its context, remember that it could be a local function or a lambda or anonymous function, defined right there within your existing function.  (Though if it's very long, that probably wouldn't improve the readability.)

Answer (score 1):

A `when` assumes that each condition leads to a single action.  (Multiple conditions can lead to the same action, but not vice versa.)  So if there's a many-to-many correspondence between conditions and actions, **I think you can't avoid *some* repetition.**

I see two main approaches:

**You can structure the code around the conditions**, and repeat the action — or at least, repeat a *reference* to it via a function — as in chand mohd's answer.

**Or you can structure the code around the actions**, and repeat the condition:

```
if (item.id == R.id.button_a)
    foo();
if (item.id == R.id.button_b || item.id == R.id_button_c))
    bar();
if (item.id == R.id.button_c)
    baz();
```

In some ways, that second way is less clean; it means repeating `item.id ==` many times, and it also means repeating `R.id_button_c`.  And it can be a little harder to follow, as the actions executed together aren't necessarily together in the code.

But it's more flexible; you don't have to repeat any of the actions, or faff around with functions.  It's easier to insert actions that are *always* exeicted.  And if you have some overall constraints (e.g. `foo()` can't be called after `bar()`, then those are easier to code and to verify.

So ultimately, **it's a trade-off.  Both approaches are valid**; the better one will depend on the details of your particular case, on the proportion of repeated conditions to that of repeated actions, on the length of the actions, on any constraints — on the *shape* of the problem you're trying to solve.